# r-value reference return type semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Does a return type like this represent something meaningful in c++11?

```
template <typename R>
R&& grabStuff();

T instance = grabStuff<T>();
```

I would hope that `grabStuff` should throw a compile-time error if `R` does not have a move constructor, since this would seem to disallow the return type to use a copy constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always, when returning references you must return a reference to something that's still alive after the function returns. How you do that is up to you. Example:

```
T global_thing;

T && get() { return std::move(global_thing); }

struct Foo { Foo(T &&); /* ... */ };

int main()
{
    global_thing.reset();
    Foo a(get());
    global_thing.reset();
    Foo b(get());
}
```

The more typical example for returning an rvalue reference is `std::move` itself, though, which returns a reference to the thing you pass *into* it (and thus it's the caller's responsibility to provide a valid input).

Comment: The object need not to be global object. A resource-managing local object is also an example (I mean, maybe :D).

Comment: @Kerrek, so what you are saying is that this function should only be called in temporaries? can't the result of `get()` in your example be assigned to a normal reference of `Foo&`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes yes, as I said, it's up to you... I just wanted to give an example that's *not* `std::move` itself.

Comment: @lurscher: You can bind the result to a reference, too: `Foo && rr = get();`.

Answer (score 3):

If the return type of a function is an rvalue reference, then the result of the function call is an xvalue; if the return type is non-reference, then the result of the function call is a prvalue.

Both xvalue and prvalue are rvalues, there are some minor differences between them, more like differences between reference and non-reference. For example, an xvalue may have an incomplete type, while a prvalue shall usually have a complete type or the void type. When typeid is applied to an xvalue whose type is a polymorphic class type, the result refers to the dynamic type; and for prvalue, the result refers to the static type.

For your declaration statement `T instance = grabStuff<T>();`, if T is a class type, I think there is no difference between xvalue and prvalue in this context.

The initializer is an rvalue, so the compiler prefers a move constructor. But if no move constructor is declared, and a copy constructor with const reference parameter is declared, then this copy constructor will be chosen, and there is no error. I don't know why do you want this to be an error. If this is an error, any old code will be incorrect when copy-initialize some object from an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

It may be meaningful depending on what you want to do with it, and how you've implemented the function.

In fact, `std::move` return type is `T&&` (rvalue reference) which is meaningful, as it defines the very purpose of the existence of `std::move` in the C++11 library:

- [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: `std::move` is the **only** meaningful instance of an rvalue-reference return type. It would never be meaningful in user code.

Comment: @ildjarn: I cannot claim that *"It would **never** be meaningful in user code"*. I'm just stating that rvalue-reference as return type, may be meaningful.

Comment: I'm claiming that. ;-] In _user code_ (unless that user code is duplicating `std::move` for some odd reason), an rvalue reference return type cannot do anything semantically meaningful.

Comment: @ildjarn: It is too early for claiming anything of that sort; C++11 just has been released, and in the next 10 years, many tricks and idioms are going to be discovered. So I will rather keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: You can either A) get a dangling reference or B) _imply_ a change of ownership without guaranteeing it, which is completely useless. That's it.