# Understanding rvalue reference on return

Tags: c++, function, c++11, rvalue-reference

For example i have code such as below

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

struct data
{
    int n;
    data()
    {
        std::cout << "data()\n";
    }
    data(const data&)
    {
        std::cout << "data(const data&)\n";
    }
    data(data&&)
    {
        std::cout << "data(data&&)\n";
    }
};

class container
{
    data d;    
public:
    data getData()
    {
        return std::move(d);
    }
};

int main()
{
    container c;
    data result = c.getData();
}
```

And output is:

```
data() 
data(data&&)
```

I don't understand how it works. I have not declared return type as `data&&`, but move constructor works fine for result. Yes, code is `std::move(d)` but return type is not `data&&`. So, how does it work?

Comment: An object constructed by using the move constructor is returned.

Comment: It is clear for me, but why? Return type is data, not data&&, and as i understand that is mean we are return data by value (not reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer changes in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

```
data getData()
{
    return std::move(d);
}
```

This method moves `d` into its return value.

```
data x = foo.getData();
```

this one constructs `x` from the return value of `getData`.  However the C++ standard encourages and permits this construction to be *elided* if `getData` returns a prvalue (a value type that matches).  Elision means that the *identity* and *lifetime* of the return value and `x` are merged.  Only one object exists, not two.

This permits skipping side effects, like print statements in move constructors.

So `d` is the object moved from, and that move directly constructs `x`.

If you change `getData` to return `data&&`, now no move is done within`getData` but one is done outside when you construct `x`.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the return value of `getData` is never an object, it is a prvalue, and prvalues in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) are more like instructions to create objects.  In effect elision is no longer optional.

Answer (score 3):

If the return type is set to `data` (as in your case), then the returned object is a prvalue.
If the return type is set to `data&&`, then the returned object is an xrvalue.

In either case, the returned object is an rvalue, and `result`'s move constructor will be called.

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10159163/4509057